# print all json objects as string using jq utility

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON value:

```json
{
  "ssh_key": {
    "id": 123
  }
}
```

How i can print **id object** by jq utility **as string**? Object value must be (with double quotas):

```json
{
  "id": "123"
}
```

I use  `jq '.ssh_key | {id}` command for print without double quotes now.

Thanks.

Comment: In the title of your Q, the phrase "all JSON objects" appears, but in JSON-speak, that has a specific meaning that does not correspond to the body of the question. Do you want all numeric values in every top-level key-value pair converted to strings, or just the numeric value corresponding to the "id" key? Or perhaps you mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `tostring` (or the `@text`) builtin to convert into a string:

```
jq '.ssh_key | .id |= tostring'
```

```
{
  "id": "123"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/78ZJQuFRfE)